# ¿Cómo mantener un dato mientras cambio de vista en APS.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema con el dato que tengo en mi sidebar: cuando cambio de vista, el dato que hace el llamado con mi view.bag no lo visualiza, ¿a qué se debe?

Este es el código que está en la sidebar del archivo _Layout

```
<ul class="siderbar_menu">
        <tr> <td><div class="col"><span><b>Contador sin días críticos:</b></span><span class="badge badge-viajes">@ViewBag.sinCritico</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr> <td><div class="col"><span><b>Último incidente:</b></span><span class="badge badge-viajes">@ViewBag.ultimoDiaCritico</span></div></td></tr>
</ul>
```

Así se ve
[image]

y Así se ve cuando cambio de vista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el controlador hace el llamado de unos datos en SQL; comparto código de controlador:

Código controller

```
public ActionResult Instructivo()
{


    /////Contador DIAS

    ViewBag.sinCritico = "";

    using (Models.statusDB db66 = new Models.statusDB())

    {
        var conn66 = new SqlConnection();
        conn66.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDconection"].ConnectionString;
        conn66.Open();
        string sql66 = @"select DATEDIFF(DAY, fechaAccidente, fechaSinAccidente) as 'DiasSinAccidentes' from [dbo].[kpiFechaAccidente]
                    ;"
                    ;

        SqlCommand cmd66 = new SqlCommand(sql66, conn66);
        SqlDataReader reader66 = cmd66.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader66.Read())
        {
            Estado valor = new Estado();
            valor.Valor = Convert.ToString(reader66["DiasSinAccidentes"]);

            ViewBag.sinCritico = valor.Valor;
        }

        reader66.Close();

        /////Contador DIAS

        ViewBag.ultimoDiaCritico = "";

        using (Models.statusDB db77 = new Models.statusDB())

        {
            var conn77 = new SqlConnection();
            conn77.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDconection"].ConnectionString;
            conn77.Open();
            string sql77 = @"select convert(char(20), fechaAccidente, 103) as 'fechaAccidente'  from [dbo].[kpiFechaAccidente] 
                             GROUP BY CONVERT(char(20), fechaAccidente, 103)
                        ;"
                        ;

            SqlCommand cmd77 = new SqlCommand(sql77, conn77);
            SqlDataReader reader77 = cmd77.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader77.Read())
            {
                Estado valor = new Estado();
                valor.Valor = Convert.ToString(reader77["fechaAccidente"]);

                ViewBag.ultimoDiaCritico = valor.Valor;
            }

            reader77.Close();
            return View();
                               
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías incluir la forma en que estas guardando el valor en tu controller?

Comment: Gracias por el detalle. Actualizado. Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo lo que estás haciendo. Tienes un controller "Instructivo" que retorna una vista, pero en el layout pones los datos desde el viewbag. En todo caso, creo que la solución más simple a tu problema, es que conviertas a Instructivo en una vista parcial, y luego desdel el _layout llames a esa vista parcial